# SHOWPLAN permission denied in database 'tempdb'. in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query when I run the below query in Include Actual Execution Plan then it throws the following error :

Execution Result :

(1 row(s) affected)

(89 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 262, Level 14, State 4, Line 25
SHOWPLAN permission denied in database 'tempdb'.

Note : Before creating CLUSTERED INDEX on temptables it is working fine. after creating  CLUSTERED INDEX it was showing the above error. how can I see the execution plan for the below query any suggestions.

Answer (score 13):

Get an admin to run the following in the `tempdb`:

```
GRANT SHOWPLAN TO <UserName>
GO
```

where `<UserName>` is your username.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had `with execute as 'dbo'` specified on my procedure. Since the dbo user is specific to a database I doubt you can grant it the SHOWPLAN permission in tempdb. Instead, I removed the `with execute as 'dbo'` clause from the procedure and I was able to continue performance testing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now, and I just had to close and re-open my Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.